# Palabras en castellano análogas a "safety" y "security" en inglés

Tags: uso-de-palabras, vocabulario, sinónimos, sustantivos

Según Google, las palabras inglesas "safety" y "security", traducidas al castellano, ambas significan "seguridad". Sin embargo, "safety" y "security" no significan exactamente lo mismo en inglés.

Por un lado, "safety" es la característica intrínseca de un objeto de ser seguro:

> **Inglés:** The device was designed with safety in mind, so feel free to experiment with it.
>
> **Castellano:** El dispositivo ha sido diseñado para que se pueda usar de manera segura, así que puedes experimentar libremente con él.

Por otro lado, "security" denota que se ha establecido un proceso o conjunto de reglas que tienen que ser ejecutados para que algo sea seguro:

> **Inglés:** We follow a strict security code to minimize the risks associated to operating in a hostile environment.
>
> **Castellano:** Seguimos un estricto código de seguridad para minimizar los riesgos asociados a operar en un entorno hostil.

Para mi mala suerte, tengo que escribir un documento formal en castellano, en el cual necesito hacer explícita la distinción entre estas dos acepciones del término "seguridad". ¿Existe algún par de palabras en castellano que me permita transmitir esta diferencia de significados?

P.D.: Mi situación es similar a la de la FSF cuando define "free software" como "free as in speech", no "free as in beer".

---

According to Google, the English words "safety" and "security" can be both translated to Spanish as "seguridad". However, "safety" and "security" do not quite mean the same thing:

> This device is [intrinsically] *safe* to use.
>
> We must follow a strict *security* code [that we had to set up because we operate in an unsafe environment].

I am writing a formal document in Spanish in which I must precisely convey the difference between these two concepts. What Spanish words could I use as drop-in replacements for "safety" and "security"?

P.D.: My situation is similar to that of the FSF when they define "free software" to be "free as in speech", not "free as in beer".

Comment: Desgraciadamene creo que [en Español](http://lema.rae.es/drae/srv/search?id=wwcs1Hw7LDXX28FVsWTl) **seguridad** designa tanto la cualidad de ser seguro como de asegurar un buen funcionamiento. Voy a investigar un poco, a ver si consigo encontrar algo.

Comment: He visto en algunos foros la distinción entre protección y seguridad, lo que pasa es que según el país algunos han recomendado protección para safety, y seguridad para security, y otros al revés =/  Otros términos según contextos: salubridad, resguardo, integridad, inocuidad.  Este última término utiliza mucha (como "inocuidad de la comida") para "food safety" mientras utiliza "seguridad alimentaria" para "food security".

Comment: @guifa: "Integridad" e "inocuidad" son particularmente convincentes. :-)

Comment: Yo usaría sinónimos, por safety tienes: protection, invulnerability, immunity; por security tienes: insurance, guarantee, bond, defense, contract, agreement, pact. En tu caso creo que podrías decir *seguimos una estricta política/norma de seguridad*.

Comment: Pues dejame decirte que antes de entrar a la pregunta vi el título y lo primero que pensé fue que *safety* y *security* se traducian como *seguridad*. Me parece la palabra mas correcta.

Comment: @JaimeCruzTriana: El problema es que necesito dos palabras distintas.

Comment: Nice reference to the FSF.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if that would be of any help, but in ICAO (and, as far as I know, in other UN bodies) Spanish translators use "seguridad operacional", whenever there's "safety" in the English document and simply "seguridad", when it is "security".

The difference between the two being that safety (seguridad operacional) is understood as inherent or built-in quality of a well-designed object, say, aircraft, in the sense that it was designed to stand the operational stresses, severe weather conditions; that there is no chance a passenger would hit his/her temple against a salient part of a carry-on luggage shelf and drop dead. Meanwhile, security (seguridad) is understood as an ability to withstand malevolent infringements: terrorist attacks, unruly passengers.

Mind that the distinction is only made whenever the two terms appear in the same text and different translations are there to avoid confusion. In other instances, both may be "seguridad", or, depending on a context, more fitting term may be found (like "integridad").

Answer (score 1):

Safety: cuidado, atención, seguridad (en el sentido de "tener precaución"). Es una acción que realiza el agente para evitar el riesgo.

Security: seguridad (en el sentido de que "existen las condiciones"). Es un estado del contexto en el que el agente se expone al riesgo.

"Juan camina con cuidado, y usa zapatos de seguridad"

Answer (score 1):

En Sudamérica, *Safety* se refiere a la seguridad industrial o laboral (accidentes, enfermedades ocupacionales), mientras que *Securite* se refiere a la protección contra riesgos intencionales (robos, hurtos, sabotajes, espionaje).

El personal de seguridad y/o higiene industrial desarrolla el *safety*, mientras que los policías, investigadores, vigilantes o agentes de vigilancia desarrollan el *security*.